# Xbox 360 Controller API Not Cooperating

Tags: c++, architecture, visual-studio-2013, xbox360, xinput

I'm trying to go through the XInput tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. However, the code from the example won't even execute because it keeps saying that, among other errors, "No Target Architecture". I've looked all over the internet and still have no idea how to define my architecture. All I'm looking to do right now is have the program tell me if a controller is connected or not. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <Xinput.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void main(){
    DWORD dwResult;

    // Retrieve the state of the controller
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < XUSER_MAX_COUNT; i++)
    {
        XINPUT_STATE state;
        ZeroMemory(&state, sizeof(XINPUT_STATE));

        // Simply get the state of the controller from XInput.
        dwResult = XInputGetState(i, &state);

        if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS){
            // Controller is connected
        }
        else
        {
            // Controller is not connected
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and using Visual Studio Professional 2013. Here are my errors (project path removed for space):

```
1   error C1189: #error :  "No Target Architecture" c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h  145 1
2   IntelliSense: #error directive: "No Target Architecture"    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  145 2
3   IntelliSense: identifier "PCONTEXT" is undefined    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  16918   11
4   IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  17529   11
5   IntelliSense: identifier "SLIST_HEADER" is undefined    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  17537   16
6   IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  17544   13
7   IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  17551   13
8   IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  17559   13
9   IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  17569   13
10  IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  17576   10
11  IntelliSense: identifier "PCONTEXT" is undefined    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h 358 9
12  IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\interlockedapi.h 51  11
13  IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\interlockedapi.h 59  13
14  IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\interlockedapi.h 67  13
15  IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\interlockedapi.h 81  13
16  IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\interlockedapi.h 94  13
17  IntelliSense: identifier "PSLIST_HEADER" is undefined   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\interlockedapi.h 102 10
18  IntelliSense: identifier "CONTEXT" is undefined c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\processthreadsapi.h  762 16
19  IntelliSense: identifier "PCONTEXT" is undefined    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinBase.h    1279    14
20  IntelliSense: identifier "PCONTEXT" is undefined    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinBase.h    8619    13
21  IntelliSense: identifier "PCONTEXT" is undefined    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinBase.h    8621    10
22  IntelliSense: identifier "PCONTEXT" is undefined    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinBase.h    8637    11
23  IntelliSense: identifier "PCONTEXT" is undefined    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinBase.h    8660    10
24  IntelliSense: identifier "PCONTEXT" is undefined    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinBase.h    8669    10
25  IntelliSense: identifier "PCONTEXT" is undefined    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinBase.h    8685    13
```

Furthermore, I've included the code for the first error. Line 145 is the line that says "No Target Architecture". There is a red line underneath "#error". Here it is:

```
#if defined(_AMD64_) || defined(_X86_)
#define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD )
#elif defined(_IA64_) || defined(_ARM_)
#define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) (TYPE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) > TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD ) ? \
                              TYPE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) : TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD ))
#elif !defined(RC_INVOKED)
#error "No Target Architecture"
#endif
```

Thanks for your help in advance. Myself and a couple other guys are having trouble with this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this correctly, you need to define the architecture of the platform your program will be running on. so put `#define _AMD64_` for example, before your includes.

If that does not help, maybe you need to add some libraries to your compiler dependency...that solved my problem.

And IIRC putting `#include<windows.h>` in front of `#include<Xinput.h>` might help as well.